# Not getting extends java.lang.Object in bytecode. so why compiler is not adding it in newer version of java?

Tags: java, bytecode

I have simple code as below

```
package prashant;
public class CheckObject {
}
```

I used **javap -c CheckObject**  and got below bytecode :

```
 Compiled from "CheckObject.java"
 public class prashant.CheckObject {
 public prashant.CheckObject();
 Code:
   0: aload_0       
   1: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4: return        
  }
```

as in older version of Java implicitly compiler was adding **extends Object**  in byte code as :

> public class prashant.CheckObject extends java.lang.Object

so i have two question regarding **extends Object**:

1)  is it not added, because of any performance hit?

2)  in which java version it got changed?

java version used to compile this code is **1.6.0_45**.

Comment: They probably changed the disassembler, not the compiler.

Comment: if i am explicitly writing extends Object then also it is not showing in byte-code.

Comment: Exactly, which proves @immibis's point. You could test whether including or excluding it changes the bytecode file, which woudl also prove the point one way or the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're printing a disassembly, not the raw bytecode, and the disassembly is designed to be human-readable. An object with no declared superclass necessarily `extends Object` (as shown by the comment on the constructor), and so listing it is redundant.

Comment: but compiler was adding in older version you can see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345043/classes-not-extending-java-lang-object

Comment: @Prashant You haven't yet produced any evidence that the compiler has changed, and your link doesn't say so either.

Comment: @EJP : i got your point but initially that was showing in byte code but not now for that i was asking.

Comment: Specifically, javap which is designed to lie to you to make things prettier.

Answer (score 2):

First off, every class must have a superclass (except for `java/lang/Object` itself). Nothing has changed regarding this.

The problem is that you're using `javap` which is designed for Java programmers and hence tends to hide inconvenient details of the classfile format to make the output seem more Java like. If you want to see what is really in the classfile you need to use a different disassembler ([such as the Krakatau disassembler](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau)).

Presumably, old versions of `javap` did not hide Object superclasses but it was later updated to hide them. Your classfiles didn't change, only your disassembler.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the issue of whether the compiler has *really* changed<sup>1</sup> ... the change is almost immaterial.

- It saves a small amount of space in the class file if there is no explicit call to the `Object` constructor.  You save 4 bytes of bytecodes, and (I think) one constant pool entry for the constructor's signature.
- When the bytecodes are still being interpreted, there *might* be a slight different in the execution speed of executing an explicit constructor call versus an implicit constructor one.  But the difference will be negligible, and I'm not prepared to predict which will be faster.

Once the code is JIT compiled, I confidently predict that there will / would be no performance difference between the two different versions of the code.  I predict that JIT compiler will generate code with equivalent speed.  (Any JIT compiler optimization for this would have have been implemented a long time ago, since the chaining to `Object<init>` applies almost every time an object is constructed.)

---

At the source code level, received wisdom is that a `super()` call in a constructor makes zero difference to performance, irrespective of what the superclass is.  Similarly, there is zero performance difference if you do or don't explicitly write `extends Object`.

The only difference of any note is to readability.  It is purely a code style issue.

---

<sup>1 - You have provide no credible evidence one way or the other.  See the comments.</sup>

Comment: As posted, the bytecode shows a call to the superclass ctor; the OP was complaining that it doesn't shown an explicit "extends" clause.

Comment: @kdgregory - But he hasn't shown the other version.  There is no evidence of >>change<<.  If there was a second version we could then drill down to what the evidence actually means ... which is probably NOT what he thinks.